# Restful App making SAFE CRUD requests to the server using php laravel

Tags: php, security, hash, laravel, token

Question may sound similar to a lot of information thats under Resful Designs.

I've read numbers of articles went through bunch of tutorials, trying to understand how Resful apps work. I see bunch of tuts. Looked into OAuth but it is not what i need..

Since security is my main concern, I have come to problem of how i should be handling nonces/hashes!??

***What do i mean by nonce/hashes is;***

I have a Restful application which uses laravel 4.1. Framework, users can log in with Auth::User() implementation. All is good. ALL REQUESTS I make to the application are CRUD.

***Why Do I want to use nonces/hash;***

Lets i have **@DELETE Route("workouts/{id}")** under api prefix in my resource
users can delete workouts using **example.com/api/workouts/1** does it not has to have also something like **{nonce}** attached to the link like **example.com/api/workouts/1/nonce/12321321313** since everyother user may fake redirect user and make a person delete its own workout?

***Most of the Articles indicates that;***
As far as I know for security concerns, I should be sending a  nonce along with **every** ajax request to the server, then server must verify and respond back to the client with informations along with new nonce for the next request? This is a performance killer but is it the way?

***HTTPS REQUESTS?? NO TOKENS/hashes or nonces?***
So some say Under HTTPS PROTOCOL after logging in safely(valid credentials) there is no need to send a nonce ( to the server) for each request (such as CRUD) anymore. Authentication with credentials is enough to authenticate user for goods.

Looking Through all of Laravel angular tutorials 
There is nothing mentioned about using tokens nonces or anything at all, at least not that I've seen of.

**My main question is how I should be designing server side routes to make safer requests to the server with laravel using tokens, nonces or hashes etc?**

I know there lots of topics but they seem very theoric to me. I dont know which are accuratly protective and which arent. So thank you for your patience of reading it and hope to gets some accurate response..

*and excuse my English :)..*

Comment: Are you creating an API?

Comment: Its techniqally not an API. Its just a restfull application that interacts between server and client thats it. no permission requirements to reach others social media apis.. @ollieread

Comment: Does your application handle frontend, or serve data to another system?

Comment: I am guessing you have not read what I wrote above. I said restful and able to do CRUD. Therfor it is indeed handling frontend-ajax-requests  in server side(insert delete upd etc) and responding back with json based information. @ollieread

Comment: Saying that something is RESTful and can do CRUD doesn't say whether or not it's serving the frontend or acting as an API. I have created several RESTful APIs that perform CRUD, it just provides json data back, not frontend.

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean by serving front-end'. But giving furter details; My front-end part of the application is written with angularjs, and it gets data by simply making get request 'to the server and reads the json to generate the content in its each dynamic route. Then Crud becomes available depending on the routes. Each request goes to the URL prefix under '/api' 'workouts' resource controller handles store() update() destroy() etc. @ollieread

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using the term RESTful application is a bit misleading. But, if you using a REST API you should have a look at JSON Web Token for authenticating users to your API.

Some helpful links here: [JSON Web Token](http://openid.net/specs/draft-jones-json-web-token-07.html), and a Laravel package [jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) and an [Angular](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/token-based-authentication-with-angularjs-nodejs--cms-22543) example, keep in mind that the Angular example is with Node.Js but it can be integrated with Laravel.

If you are using just AJAX requests to PHP scripts for CRUD why not use a package for protecting against CSRF attacks for Laravel, just google it and you find more tutorials.